# Using PHP variables from an array to insert into SQL database. (Syntax error)

Tags: php, sql

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Here's the line throwing the error.

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO movies (id, title, year) VALUES($arr['title_id'], $arr['title'], $arr['year'])");
```

Comment: plsease, please use prepared statements

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to surround your variables in curly braces:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO movies (id, title, year) VALUES({$arr['title_id']}, {$arr['title']}, {$arr['year']})");
```

Take a look at my `complex (curly) braces` explanation here: [Problem escaping php variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342304/problem-escaping-php-variable/7342327#7342327)

Answer (score 2):

The code that worked for me is as follows:

```
$result = mysql_query("
INSERT INTO movies (id, title, year) 
VALUES(" . implode($arr,', ').";
```

Using implode you get all the items on the array, using the '`,` ' as separation character.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the [PHP documentation about strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) to find out why your code is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO movies (id, title, year) VALUES($arr['title_id'], $arr['title'], $arr['year'])");
```

I would do it this way:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO movies (id, title, year) VALUES(" . $arr['title_id']. ", " . $arr['title'] . ", " . $arr['year'] . ")");
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you should use curly braces, or string concatenation using the `.` operator to embed the variables in your string.

Additionally, assuming that the `title` column is a `VARCHAR` field and the other two are `INT` fields, you have to put quotes around the `title` value:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO movies (id, title, year) VALUES(" . $arr['title_id'] . ", '" . $arr['title'] . "', " . $arr['year'] . ")");
```

You would have to do the same for the `id` and `year` fields if they were also `VARCHAR` fields.

Answer (score 1):

This is a string parsing problem. See the [PHP documentation on variable parsing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).
The problem is that the index is written without quotes when using simple syntax (without curly braces).

You can either use curly braces around your variables:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO movies (id, title, year) VALUES({$arr['title_id']}, {$arr['title']}, {$arr['year']})");
```

Or you can concatenate strings and variables together with dots, avoiding string parsing altogether:

```
$result = mysql_query('INSERT INTO movies (id, title, year) VALUES('.$arr['title_id'].', '.$arr['title'].', '.$arr['year'].')');
```

Or leave out the quotes, but this doesn't look too clean:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO movies (id, title, year) VALUES($arr[title_id], $arr[title], $arr[year])");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but I'd highly recommend moving to [PHP Data Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) if possible. Supports many of the higher level mysql functions like prepared statements (no more worries of sql injection), pulling data directly into objects, etc.